# jQuery validate multiple select options per page

Tags: jquery, select

I have many `select` boxes on a page form. I am trying to find a way to check all the select options rather than doing `if/else` for each one.

So far I have tried `!==` and `!=` and empty

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
    <option value="0">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
</select>

<select name="cakes" id="cakes">
    <option value="0">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="1">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="2">Strawberry</option>
</select>

<select name="breads" id="breads">
    <option value="0">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="1">Garlic Bread</option>
    <option value="2">Baker Loaf</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript (jQuery)

```
function checkEmpty(){
    var flag = 0;

    if(
        $('select').val()!=="" ||
        $('select').val()!=="-- Choose --" ||
        $('select').val()!=="0"){
            flag=1;
            $('select').addClass('error');
    } else {
            $('select').removeClass('error');
    }

    if(flag==1){
        alert('One or all options must be selected!');
    } else {
        console.log('The user made a selection');
    }

}
```

The user needs to choose one of the select boxes or all of them. One must at least be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using  `filter()`,

```
var selects = $("select");
var selected = selects.filter(function(){ return this.value !== "0" });
var res = selects.length - selected.length
if(res == selects.length - 1 || res == 0){
  console.log('The user made a selection');
} else {
  console.log('One or all options must be selected!');
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ryhdep5/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think this is elegant?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Yeah. It will be more efficient too.

Comment: Your code does not work if you do not choose an option for the first box. Or if I have 6 boxes and I choose an option for the first 6 and not the second 6.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Sorry, I cannot understand. Can you plz explain a bit/

Comment: I tried the code above with six select boxes and one submit button. If you select the first three boxes and leave the other three as empty it triggers an error, see: my attachment: http://imgur.com/BCxrYwG and code here: http://jsbin.com/pidivadife/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
function checkEmpty(){
  var checked = 0;
  $('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=="0")
    checked++;
  });
  if(checked===3||checked===1){
    //your code
  }
}
```